# Difference in output between predict.rpart and predict.glm

Tags: r, glm, predict, tidymodels

I split a dataset up in a training and test sample. I then fit a logit model on the training data to predict the outcome of the test sample. I can do this in two ways:

Using Tidyverse:

```
logit_mod <- logistic_reg() %>% 
 set_mode("classification") %>% 
 set_engine("glm") %>%
 fit(y ~ x + z, data=train)
res <- predict(logit_mod, new_data = test, type="prob")
```

Or with the GLM class:

```
logit_mod <- glm(y ~ x + z, data=train, family='logit')
res <- predict(logit_mod, newdata=test, type="response")
```

Both methods give me different output (probabilities of y). While the model should be the same. extracting `logit_mod[["fit"]]` gives me the same coefficients as I have for `logit_mod` using GLM.

Why does the second method give me different predicted probabilities?

Comment: You can try change `family = 'logit'` to `family = 'binomail'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `predict` on a `glm` binomial regression, you get the probability of the positive class, and the probabilities from `tidymodels` are rounded up.

For example, a simple regression with response as 0/1, 1 being positive class :

```
library(tidymodels)
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(y = factor(rbinom(50,1,0.5)),x=runif(50),z=runif(50))
train = df[1:40,]
test = df[41:50,]

logit_mod <- logistic_reg() %>% 
 set_mode("classification") %>% 
 set_engine("glm") %>%
 fit(y ~ x + z, data=train)
res <- predict(logit_mod, new_data = test, type="prob")
```

This is the prediction for class 1 :

```
res$.pred_1
       41        42        43        44        45        46        47        48 
0.3186626 0.3931925 0.4259043 0.3651420 0.6670263 0.6732433 0.5844562 0.5584770 
       49        50 
0.6791727 0.7567285
```

Do glm and you can see its exactly the same:

```
fit <- glm(y ~ x + z, data=train, family=binomial)
res2 <- predict(fit, newdata=test, type="response")

res2
       41        42        43        44        45        46        47        48 
0.3186626 0.3931925 0.4259043 0.3651420 0.6670263 0.6732433 0.5844562 0.5584770 
       49        50 
0.6791727 0.7567285
```